# Simple Rails routing, doing a get 'action' inside resource block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Consider this in routes.rb

```
resource :places do
    resource :people
    get 'search'
end
```

When I do this in browser:

```
localhost:3000/places/search
```

It gives me invalid id for place error.

I'm looking to do this without using a "match"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that the `get` applies to the collection:

```
resource :places do
  resource :people
  get 'search', :on => :collection
end
```

See the [documentation on collection routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes) for details.

Answer (score 1):

```
resources :places do
    resources :people
    get 'search', :on => :collection
end
```